# Check svn status of repository in local path

Tags: svn

Is there a command to check if a given local path is a working copy of a given repository?

I need to check whether a folder already contains a working copy of the repo, if it does I'll run an update if it doesn't I'll clear the folder's content and then do a checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just run

```
svn info
```

in the directory in question. That will tell you the repository for which the directory is a working copy, if any. See here for more information:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re13.html